# Regex does not work in large string with html content [PHP]

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get values such R $ XX, XX [X is an example] using regular expression but I can not.
Below is my code:

```
$str = 'Indicada para 21 velocidades, corente indexadaCAPACETE MTB MANTUA MUSIC R$140,00PEDIVELA SHIMANO DEORE R$380,00PEDIVELA SHIMANO TX-71 R$99,00CORRENTE SHIMANO HG 40 R$55,00ROLO PARA TREINAMENTO TRANZ-X R$545,00CAPACETE MTB HIGH ONE (PROMOÃ‡ÃƒO) R$85,00BOMBA DE PÃ‰ HIGH ONE COM MANÃ”METRO (NYLON) R$89,90CAPA SELIM GEL (PRÃ“-SPIN) R$45,00SUPORTE DE PAREDE VERTICAL R$20,00SUPORTE DE PAREDE HORIZONTAL R$35,00SUPORTE DE PAREDE VERTICAL PRETO R$28,00ESPUMA PARA GUIDÃƒO R$11,00BOMBA DE PÃ‰ BETO NYLON R$55,00

Bomba pÃ© nylon, acompanha adaptadores: valvula,bola e inflÃ¡veisALAVANCA SHIMANO XT DUAL CONTROL EFM 761 R$500,00

Alavanca (par) 27 velocidades com manetes para freios mecÃ¢nicos, com tecnologia "Dual Control" que chega muito prÃ³ximo do sistema "STI" das bikes de corrida.

&nbsp;SAPATILHA SHIMANO MTB M 064 R$285,00

Pele sintÃ©tica e malha flexÃ­vel, resistentes ao esticar.
Entressola de poliamida reforÃ§ada com fibra de de vidro.
PamilhaÂ  estruturalmente flexÃ­vel de acordo com uma ampla variedade de formatos de pÃ©.
Volume + forma para melhor acomodaÃ§Ã£o dos dedos dos pÃ©s.
ProteÃ§Ã£o em borracha oferece excelante traÃ§Ã£o e conforto para o caminhar.
Indicada para o pedal PD-M530, PD-M520.
Acompanha a base interna da sapatilha.ALAVANCA SHIMANO EF 51 R$130,00

Alavanca shimano 21 vel, ez-fire c/ maneteCAMPAINHA "I LOVE MY BIKE" R$14,00
Em alumÃ­nio, nas cores: polido, preto, azul e vermelho.
FÃ¡cil fixaÃ§Ã£o no guidÃ£o.CAPACETE INFANTIL R$57,00CESTA ALUMÃNIO E NYLON
';

$regex = "/R\$[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}/";

$result = preg_match_all($regex, $content, $rs);

var_dump($rs);
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$content = "R$13,57 more text R$123,456";
$regex = "/$.*(R\$[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}).*^/";
$result = preg_match_all($regex, $content, $rs);
var_dump($rs);
```

You need to place the group you are trying to match inside parentheses.